# How can I use a custom initializer on a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell and I'd like to use it in my table view. Here's my code for the cell:

```
class ReflectionCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var header: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var content: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var author: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

init(data: Reflection) {
    self.header.text = data.title
    self.content.text = data.content
    self.author.text = data.author.name
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "reflectionCell")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

I have a model class `Reflection` that I'd like to initialize the cell with. However, in my view controller I need to use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reflectionCell", for: indexPath)`. Is there any way for me to use a custom initializer like the one I made?

Comment: TableViewCell are reused, you don't do that. What you could do is creating a method `updateWith(data:Reflection)` and set the labels values, or a property `var data:Reflection` and on the `didSet`, set the values of the labels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `dequeueReusableCell` you cannot change which initializer method that is called. But you can write your own method to update the IBOutlets which you then call after you successfully dequeue a cell.

```
class ReflectionCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var header: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var content: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var author: UILabel!

    func update(for reflection: Reflection) {
        header.text = reflection.title
        content.text = reflection.content
        author.text = reflection.author.name
    }

}
```

And

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! ReflectionCell
    cell.update(for: reflections[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: The point is to initialize the cell, not to update it.  The scenario must let you add views the first time at instantiation.  The accepted answer can be replaced by a didSet closure of a stored variable.

Comment: The whole point of `dequeueReusableCell` is to explicitly _not_ initialize a new cell for every row, but rather, where possible, see if there is a previously used cell that is now available for reuse and just update it.