# Working around not having a custom init method when using a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

How can I work around not being able to have a custom `init` method when I setup a custom `UITableViewCell`? I've seen [How can I use a custom initializer on a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842034/how-can-i-use-a-custom-initializer-on-a-uitableviewcell), however, I'm adding constraints which I'd like to override in my `init` method. I need to add a text field which will be formatted differently e.g. numeric.

I've tried inheriting from my `UITableViewCell` class and setting the style enum in my `init` method, but I can't set this before calling `super.init`.

```
class LabelIntegerTextfieldTableViewCell: LabelTextfieldTableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.textFieldStyle = .Integer
// 'self' used in property access 'textFieldStyle' before 'super.init' call

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
```

```
open class LabelTextfieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    public var label = UILabel()
    public var textField = UITextField()
    public var textFieldStyle = eTextfieldStyle.Integer

    override public init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        switch textFieldStyle
        {
        case .Integer:
            textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
            textField.textAlignment = .right
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
// snip

        if (textFieldStyle == .MediumText)
        {
            contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint
              .constraints(withVisualFormat: 
              "H:|-[label]-[textField(==label)]-|", 
              options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        }
        else
        {
            contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint
              .constraints(withVisualFormat: 
              "H:|-[label]-[textField(100)]-|", 
              options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        }
```

I know in that other SO post it mentions using an `update` method, but as I say I'd rather not remove constraints and other parts.

Comment: Have you tried using convinience init?

Comment: Cells are reused, so you will need fo reconfigure your cell constraints anyway. You could use a `didSet` observer on your `textFieldStyle` property.

Comment: Thanks @Let's_Create but I have the same issue using a convince init, still can't use it before the super call to init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're trying to achieve is not actually a good design because `UITableViewCell`s are reused. So you shouldn't rely on configuring they appearance in the `init` method. For instance, you can instantiate a cell passing `Integer` style and later, if you set the cell to have a different style, you will have an inconsistent state (since what you will be seeing won't reflect what you set). That being said, you should consider using a more reactive approach, where your cell behaves according to what is set, whenever is set. In your case, you might want to take a look in `didSet` property observer. You'd have something like bellow:

```
public var textFieldStyle = eTextfieldStyle.Integer {
  didSet {
    updateAppearance()
  }
}

func updateAppearance() {
  switch textFieldStyle {
    case .Integer:
      // ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

And in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` you just need to set the proper style, as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your cell identifier goes here", for: indexPath)

  // Here you obtain the proper style depending on the index path, for instance:
  if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.textFieldStyle = .Integer
  } else {
    cell.textFieldStyle = . MediumText
  }
  return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some implementation code for the `cellForRowAt` method? I'm not sure if I should be providing my constraints in my init method or sole in `updatrAppearance`

Answer (score 0):

Since cells are re-used and may well be created through `dequeueReusableCell(reuseIdentifier:indexPath:)`, you often don't do anything specific in the `init` methods.

In your case I would suggest that you create a function that configures your cell based on the `textFieldStyle` property (removing any previous configuration, such as constraints if necessary; This may mean that you need to keep a reference to those constraints in properties).

You can call this function in two places:

1. In `awakeFromNib` if you are using a storyboard) or `init(style:reuseIdentifier:) if you aren't, to configure the cell according to the default value of`textFieldStyle`
2. In a `didSet` observer from `textFieldStyle` itself.

e.g.

```
open class LabelTextfieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    public var label = UILabel()
    public var textField = UITextField()
    public var textFieldStyle = eTextfieldStyle.Integer {
       didSet {
           self.configureCell()
       }
    }

    override public init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
{
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.configureCell()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()
         self.configureCell()
    }

    private func configureCell() {


        switch textFieldStyle {
        case .Integer:
            textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
            textField.textAlignment = .right
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
// snip

        if (textFieldStyle == .MediumText)
        {
            contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint
          .constraints(withVisualFormat: 
          "H:|-[label]-[textField(==label)]-|", 
          options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        }
        else
        {
            contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint
          .constraints(withVisualFormat: 
          "H:|-[label]-[textField(100)]-|", 
          options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        }
```

In your `cellForRow(at:)` you would simply dequeue a reusable cell and set its type:

```
    cell.textFieldStyle = .MediumText
```

An alternative approach is just to create three different subclasses and associate them with different re-use identifiers.  Then you can configure the cell once in `awakeFromNib`/`init`